# Validar dirección geografica con gmap angularjs js

Tags: javascript, ionic, angular

Validar si una dirección escrita en un input es valida con js o angular js en ionic

```
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="direccion">
  </label>
</div>
<button style="margin-bottom: 30px !important;" class="button  button-stable btnAddDir "><i class="ion-checkmark-circled"></i> Agregar </button>
```

ej: calle 10 # 11-12 barranquilla
al precionar el botan agregar realizar la validacion respectiva

Comment: Frd, toda la informacion ha de estar en la pregunta, no en los comentarios. Por favor, [edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28008) tu pregunta para añadir la direccion valida

Comment: claro amigo @x-rw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var direccionesServicio = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var panorama;
    var calle =  document.getElementById("direccion").value;
   var address = calle;
    var myLatLng;

    function iniciar() {
var calle =  document.getElementById("direccion").value;
       var address = calle;
      panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"));

      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          myLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;

          // find a Streetview location on the road
          var request = {
            origin: address,
            destination: address,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
          };
          direccionesServicio.route(request, direcionesCallback);
        } else {
          alert("el servicio tiene problemas: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', iniciar);

    function processSVData(data, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {

        panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);

        var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(data.location.latLng, myLatLng);
        panorama.setPov({
          heading: heading,
          pitch: 0,
          zoom: 1
        });
        panorama.setVisible(true);

      } else {
        alert("no se encontro esa direccion");
      }
    }

    function direcionesCallback(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var latlng = response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location;
        sv.getPanoramaByLocation(latlng, 50, processSVData);
      } else {
        alert("el servicio tiene problemas:" + status);
      }
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
    <div id="pano" style="width: 425px; height: 400px;float:left"></div>

<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
<input id="direccion" type="text" placeholder="direccion" value="e 58 ave">
  </label>
</div>

<button style="margin-bottom: 30px !important;" class="button  button-stable btnAddDir " onclick="iniciar();"><i class="ion-checkmark-circled" ></i> Agregar </button>
```